# how to use multiple count from table

Tags: sql, select, count

i'm having problem
my table:

```
ID State   Club
--------------
1  Alabama Red
2  Alabama Green
3  Florida Red
4  Alaska  Red
```

i'm need this result

example:

```
Alabama,count(red),Count(Green),Count(blue),Count(Yellow)
Alaska,count(red),Count(Green),Count(blue),Count(Yellow)
Florida,count(red),Count(Green),Count(blue),Count(Yellow)
```

how to select query ???

Comment: share your output

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation

```
select state, 
       count(case when club = 'Red' then 1 end) Red,
       count(case when club = 'Green' then 1 end) Green,
       count(case when club = 'Blue' then 1 end) Blue,
       count(case when club = 'Yellow' then 1 end) Yellow
from table
group by state
```

Answer (score 1):

Another answer using PIVOT.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT ID,State,Club FROM myTable 
) s
PIVOT
(
COUNT(ID) FOR Club IN ([Red],[Green],[Yellow])
) pvt
```

Comment: you can change list of Colors as per your requirement